# Positioning 8 buttons on two rows using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's my code:

```css
.content-achievements {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.achievements-title {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
  height: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.achievements-list {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.achievements-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.achievements-item {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 6rem;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-achievements">
            <div class="achievements-title">
                Game Achievements
            </div>
            <div class="achievements-list">
                <ul class="achievements-items">
                    <li class="achievements-item">1</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">2</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">3</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">4</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">5</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">6</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">7</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">8</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I'd like my buttons to contain the number (for some reason they don't even though I think they should've) but my main problem is grouping them on two rows (4 on each).

I tried this way:

```css
.content-achievements {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.achievements-title {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
  height: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.achievements-list {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.achievements-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.achievements-item {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 6rem;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    flex: 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-achievements">
            <div class="achievements-title">
                Game Achievements
            </div>
            <div class="achievements-list">
                <ul class="achievements-items">
                    <li class="achievements-item">1</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">achiev2</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">achiev3</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">achiev4</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">achiev5</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">achiev6</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">achiev7</li>
                    <li class="achievements-item">achiev8</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I get the exact opposite: 4 rows, 2 columns, when I need 2 rows, 4 columns, and also my circles get swayed.

How can I keep my circles the way they are and also group all my buttons on 2 rows?

Comment: If you want the items to be 4 columns then each cannot be more than 25% wide....

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm sorry for that, I got lost in my files lol. I edited it to 25% wide as it should be, but I still don't get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

To get the numbers inside your circles, I just change one value (I marked it in the code ;) )

And to obtain 2 rows, I just create manually 2 rows.

```css
.content-achievements {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.achievements-title {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
  height: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.achievements-list {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.achievements-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.achievements-item {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 2rem; /* <= I change this value, previous was 6rem */
    margin: 0 1rem;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-achievements">
  <div class="achievements-title"> Game Achievements </div>
    <div class="achievements-list">
      <ul class="achievements-items"> <!-- row 1 -->
        <li class="achievements-item">1</li>
        <li class="achievements-item">2</li>
        <li class="achievements-item">3</li>
        <li class="achievements-item">4</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="achievements-items"> <!-- row 2 -->
        <li class="achievements-item">5</li>
        <li class="achievements-item">6</li>
        <li class="achievements-item">7</li>
        <li class="achievements-item">8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```